Would it be possible to plumb the toilet waste pipe in the opposite side of the existing soil downpipe?
I would like to move this toilet to the wall on the left side of the picture:

The bathroom is in a flat with two flats above, so the soil pipe is actively used by these other flats. Here is the current plumbing:

In order to move the toilet I would like to move the waste pipe so it is plumbed into this side of the soil down pipe:

Would this be possible, to add plumb a new toilet waste pipe into this side with minimum disruption? If so how would you recommend achieving this?

Is that some kind of wall-drain toilet?

After doing some research I found this which is a near identical situation:
https://community.screwfix.com/threads/soil-stack-branch-replacement-help-please.239968/
TLDR;

Attempt to rotate the branch, this maybe possible if it is pushfit.
If it won't budge the branch needs to be cut out by making two cuts above and one below. Clips and straps are needed to secure the soil pipe while doing this.
A slip socket, or a flexible 110mm connector (with jubilee clips) will be needed to fit the new branch in the new position.

